# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter netcore 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, badimageformatexception

I got this exception when I run my project in docker container with netcore 1.1

> to type 'System.String'. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could
> not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can
> only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load
> a reference assembly for execution.

When I check all the published folders I can find the System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.

Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your program is trying to load a **reference assembly**. There is no executable code in a reference-assembly (it's a stub `*.dll` that contains only .NET metadata). You need a "real" assembly. Check your project reference paths. You should be using NuGet.

Comment: Also, why are you targeting .NET Core 1.1? That's 4+ years out of date. We're on .NET 5.0 now!

Comment: thank you.. let me try and get back to you soon... and the reason is I have to maintain the old source code from 2018.. ;(

Comment: I tried to install that dll with version 4.0.0 but it said that not compatible with net core 1.1 (even in the log that through cannot found version 4.0.0).. where I can find the compatible version with 1.1 net core?

Comment: BadImageFormatException usually mean you run with wrong platform target. for example you are running on x86 but your reference is x64